# Are there any risks selling subdomains?

Tags: dns, sub-domain

I am considering buying a nice domain name (say `example.com`) and would be interested in reselling subdomains (e.g. `chris.example.com`) to third parties (or close friends). I would give them full control over the zone via the use of `NS` records.

Ignoring liability issues, are there any Internet security issues that may be in play here?

- For example, is there any popular software that considers subdomains part of the parent domain and shares information (e.g. HTTP cookies or CORS)?
- Do email providers consider subdomains as part of the parent domain for spam reputation?

So yeah, beyond liability and business stuff, is there anything I should be worried about?

Comment: *"e.g. HTTP cookies..."* - yes, cookies are often applied to subdomains too. To cite from [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) of the `domain` attribute: *"If a domain is specified, __subdomains are always included__."*

Comment: You need to add your domain to the Public Suffix List